# Why are my nav bar links in the wrong order?

Tags: html, css

So I've got a nav bar on my website but the links are in the wrong order on the desktop screen size. Why is it like this? and how can I fix it? They are in the right order for the mobile menu but not desktop screen size. If I change it to float: left then they are in the right order but I want them to be on the right hand side so I changed it to float: right.

Here is my html code:

```
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <p style="display:inline"><img src=' 'width="30" height="30" >IP tutorials</p>

  <a href="{{ url_for('studentdashboard') }}" class="active">Home</a>

  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Work
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
       <a href="{{ url_for('courseprogress') }}">Courses</a>
                  <a href="{{ url_for('projectprogress') }}">Projects</a>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Other
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
     <a href="{{ url_for('certificates') }}">Certificates</a>
                      <a href="{{ url_for('supportpage') }}">Support</a>
                      <a href="{{ url_for('messages') }}">Messages</a>
                      <a href="{{ url_for('payment') }}">Payments</a>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Account
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="{{ url_for('studentprofile') }}">Profile</a>
                          <a href="{{ url_for('studentaccount') }}">Account details</a>
                          <a href="{{ url_for('studentsettings') }}">Settings</a>
                          <a href="{{ url_for('logout') }}">Log out</a>
      
    </div>
  </div>
 
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS code :

```
/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
.topnav {
  background-color: #d4d4d4;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
  float: right;
  display: block;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Add an active class to highlight the current page */
.active {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: white;
}

/* Hide the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */
.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

/* Dropdown container - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
  float: right;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Style the dropdown button to fit inside the topnav */
.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

/* Style the dropdown content (hidden by default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Style the links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

/* Add a dark background on topnav links and the dropdown button on hover */
.topnav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: white;
}

/* Add a grey background to dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

/* Show the dropdown menu when the user moves the mouse over the dropdown button */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

/* When the screen is less than 600 pixels wide, hide all links, except for the first one ("Home"). Show the link that contains should open and close the topnav (.icon) */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child), .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

/* The "responsive" class is added to the topnav with JavaScript when the user clicks on the icon. This class makes the topnav look good on small screens (display the links vertically instead of horizontally) */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive a.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown {float: none;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: right;
  }
}
```

Here is what it looks like : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v50Rd.png)

Comment: `float: right;`

Comment: `.dropdown {
  float: right;
  overflow: hidden;
}`
Try removing float: right from this?

Comment: _“Why is it like this?”_ – _because_ you floated them right, that is how that _works._ The first item gets put all the way to the right, and then what comes next goes _to the left_ of that. _“but I want them to be on the right hand side”_ - go with `display:inline-block` instead of float then, and align them via `text-align` on the parent element. Or go look into _contemporary_ layouting systems like flexbox.

Comment: This is just a copy-paste from W3Schools. It's clear that you don't understand the code if you just copy it. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_responsive_navbar_dropdown